# Why can't I change my Visual Studio 2010 default project directory?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I try to create a new project, by clicking

<kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>New</kbd>→<kbd>Project</kbd>,

the dialog's default project location does **not** default to the directory shown in

<kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Options</kbd>→[Projects and Solutions]→
[General]→"Projects location:".

But it is pointing instead to an old project of mine.

Is there another place this value is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this was resolved by changing the following registry key to the desired default project location:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\NewProjectDialog\MRUSettingsLocalProjectLocationEntries\Value0
```